# Regex look behind and replace if not found

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove double forward slashes in my string which is a url, but I do not want to remove the `http://` bit, which the url will always have, so far I have came up with this but it not working,

```
#[//[^(?<=http:)]]#
```

It is not replacing the `http://` bit but it also isn't replacing the parts that I do want it to replace.

Thank you

Comment: What's with all the square brackets?

Comment: I don't know regex very well I have tried learning from tutorials online, but it is hard!

Comment: No worries; just making sure I didn't misunderstand what you were attempting. Square brackets won't be needed for this task.

Comment: @speakr Square brackets function as __character classes__, so anything inside (with the exception of a few special characters) are quite literal. That lookbehind is no longer a lookbehind...which is why I asked  :)

Comment: @KennethK. Yes, I got it wrong - I translated "square brackets" accidentally to "hash keys". ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this regexp with negative look-behind:

```
/(?<!http:)\/\//i
```

Comment: Note that PCRE requires delimiters around the regexp.

Comment: +1, but consider to do it with case-insensitive flag if it is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(?<!http:)\/\//i', '_', $url);
```